# Multiple Linq.Tables in method

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I've created a little bit of code which adds data from Linq.Tables (dc.GTMD_Financials) to a UserControl. For every entry in the database it shows a new usercontrol.

But i would like to use this code in a method to reuse it throughout the application. My problem is that each time i call the method i would like to use a different table from the database (so GTMD_Financials changes)

I can't seem to figure it out and would really appreciate any form of help or example.

```
        int locationControl = 78;
        DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        dc.GTMD_Financials.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            KPIEntrys uc = new KPIEntrys();         // UserControl

            uc.KPI = x.KPI;                         // Add data to properties
            uc.Status = x.Status.ToString();
            uc.Goal = x.Goal.ToString();
            uc.Currently = x.Currently.ToString();
            bool checkaction = x.ShowAction == true ? uc.ShowAction = true : uc.ShowAction = false;
            bool checkstats = x.ShowStats == true ? uc.ShowStats = true : uc.ShowStats = false;
            bool checkstatus = x.Status < x.StatusSignal ? uc.StatusGood = true : uc.StatusGood = false;

            uc.Location = new Point(21, locationControl);
            this.Controls.Add(uc);                  // Add Control to Form

            locationControl = locationControl + 34;
        }
        );
```

If something is unclear please let me know.
Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

I can't seem to get it working with the help i already got. I was able to edit the method a little bit with the help from replys i already got:

```
    int locationControl = 78;
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    public List<Control> LoadKPIs(Table<GTMD_Financial> dbTable)
    {
        var controls = new List<Control>();            

        dbTable.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            KPIEntrys uc = new KPIEntrys();

            uc.KPI = x.KPI;
            uc.Status = x.Status.ToString();
            uc.Goal = x.Goal.ToString();
            uc.Currently = x.Currently.ToString();
            uc.ShowAction = (bool)x.ShowAction;
            uc.ShowStats = (bool)x.ShowStats;
            uc.StatusGood = x.Status < x.StatusSignal;
            uc.Location = new Point(21, locationControl);

            controls.Add(uc);

            locationControl = locationControl + 34;
        }
        );
        return controls;
    }
```

So let me rephrase my question: How can i change the class when i call the method: LoadKPIs(Table<**GTMD_Financial**> dbTable? So GTMD_Finacial changes.

Comment: Which pieces of code would you like to reuse? There will be pieces which you can reuse, and pieces you cannot reuse. You have to be very clear about that if you want to create a reusable method; what does it actually do?

Comment: "dc.GTMD_Financials" is the only thing that changes. Next time i call it i would like to use "dc.GTMD_Organisation" (or another one)

Comment: the only thing i see that you need is to get the current needed table to this method instead of dc.GTMD_Financials

Comment: yes indeed, but that's the thing i can't seem to figure out.

Comment: do all the tables contain the properties KPI, Status,Goal, Currently, ShowAction,ShowStats, StatusSignal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write an interface which defines all the properties you want to use, and implement that on the business entities that you want to use.

```
public interface IMyReusableInterface {
    string KPI { get; set; }
    string Status { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public partial GTMD_Financials: IMyReusableInterface {
}
```

Now you can write a reusable method which accepts a list of objects which implement that interface.

```
public List<Control> MyReusableMethod (List<IMyReusableInterface> data) {
    int locationControl = 78;
    var controls = new List<Control>();

    foreach (var x in data) {
        KPIEntrys uc = new KPIEntrys();         // UserControl

        uc.KPI = x.KPI;                         // Add data to properties
        uc.Status = x.Status.ToString();
        uc.Goal = x.Goal.ToString();
        uc.Currently = x.Currently.ToString();
        // I've simplefied the boolean checks.
        uc.ShowAction = x.ShowAction;
        uc.ShowStats = x.ShowStats;
        uc.StatusGood = x.Status < x.StatusSignal;
        uc.Location = new Point(21, locationControl);

        controls.Add(uc);                  // Add Control to Form

        locationControl = locationControl + 34;
    }

    return controls;
}
```

And use it:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
this.Controls.AddRange(
    MyReusableMethod(
        dc.GTMD_Financials
            .Cast<IMyReusableInterface>()
            .ToList()
    )
);
```

Comment: Thnx for yout input, however i can't seem to get it to work..Probably a fault on my behalf. Can't seem to create "public partial GTMD_Financials: IMyReusableInterface {
}" and next i get an error when trying to use "Controls", it can't be found.

Comment: Controls should be Control.ControlCollection, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx. I'll fix that.

Comment: And you should implement the IMyReusableInterface interface on the classes that you want to use with the method.

Comment: Thank for changing, getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.Control>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'" error. Also thanks for simplifying the bool's, stupid of mine..

Comment: My apologies, it should be a list of controls, List<Control>.

Comment: Worked, thnx. I'm very sorry, but can you show me how to use that partial part in an example?

Comment: If you have it working, then what is the problem with the partial part? Partial basically means that you split the class in multiple files. I assumed you where using a EF edmx, and since the classes are then generated, you have to add custom logic to the business entity with a partial class in separate file.

Answer (score 2):

hopefully i got it right

```
public void myMethod(List<TSource> y)
int locationControl = 78;
    y.ForEach(x =>
    {
        KPIEntrys uc = new KPIEntrys();         // UserControl

        uc.KPI = x.KPI;                         // Add data to properties
        uc.Status = x.Status.ToString();
        uc.Goal = x.Goal.ToString();
        uc.Currently = x.Currently.ToString();
        bool checkaction = x.ShowAction == true ? uc.ShowAction = true : uc.ShowAction = false;
        bool checkstats = x.ShowStats == true ? uc.ShowStats = true : uc.ShowStats = false;
        bool checkstatus = x.Status < x.StatusSignal ? uc.StatusGood = true : uc.StatusGood = false;

        uc.Location = new Point(21, locationControl);
        this.Controls.Add(uc);                  // Add Control to Form

        locationControl = locationControl + 34;
    }
    );
```

Comment: Ok nice, but how do i use a Linq.Table as <TSource>? Sorry for my limited knowledge.

Comment: it's ok, i'm know how it fells, actually you don't use TSource, u use a type you created and know that type has all the properties you need. it can be abstract type, or interface also

Comment: I'm having troubles to create a type which contains everything. Must it be something like: public class { internal string KPI }? Or am i totally wrong here. Kind of new to these things.

Comment: @Marcel do you need me to give a sample to you?

Comment: I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @Marcel i'm sorry, i'm miles from my computer and can do that just on sunday... terribly sorry, wish you would have comment yesterday

Comment: Thanks i understand. I'll wait for it if i won't be able to solve it myself.